# What does "killmenothing" in a cookie mean?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I encountered this using Fiddler, e.g.:

> Request sent 57 bytes of Cookie data: killmenothing;
>   ASP.NET_SessionId=3vufx3vqzzlm4q55xhoej4go

Could someone please explain me the exact meaning?

UPDATE:
I finally managed to find the source: it's a way to make sure a cookie exists by setting one, just as described quite a bit of time ago in [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210428071600/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/082400-1.shtml).
Thanks for your contributions that helped me to address my search in the right direction.

Comment: This seems to be data - that is, the website you're accessing put that there.

Comment: since only the website that sent the data can update the cookie, ask them what this cookies does.

Comment: @KevinDTimm: You may want to laugh at me, but it's ours... a very large and complex one, and I just can't figure out where this entry comes from.

Comment: Nope, not laughing - very interesting issue - I'll be watching

Answer (score 3):

This is not a built in feature.

Looks like a way for the website developer to eradicate certain cookie data by replacing it with that string.

Answer (score 1):

Check your web config. Its possible its the cookie name used for authentication.